# What happens if I sent larger UDP packet size than 2 smaller MTUs

Tags: tcp, udp, ip, fragment, mtu

Suppose there are two routers between two hosts, each with an MTU size of 500 and 200. If you send 600 bytes of data from one side, how does the data come into the other host? In other words, how does the size of each Fragment come in?

Answer (score 1):

The datagram will get fragmented on the first link and then the fragments will get fragmented on the second link. That assumes, of course, that the "DF" (don't fragment) bit isn't set.